# Filtrar trecho de campo String em MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, regex

Estou com dificuldade em conseguir apenas o CEP de um campo na qual os dados de endereço não são atômicos, gostaria de saber uma maneira usando MySQL de obter apenas os 8 valores numéricos do trecho de CEP do campo de todos os registros da base que contenham 8 dígitos sucessivos e se possível considerando os casos onde há hífen separador (-) mas trazendo apenas os números como resultado da seleção.

Valores típicos no campo da tabela de interesse: (dados do campo endereço)

BR-50670901 Recife, PE, Brazil.

BR-70910900 Brasilia, DF, Brazil.

BR-14040901 Ribeirao Preto, SP, Brazil.

BR-74001970 Goiania, Go, Brazil.

Nucleo Fis Aplicada, BR-70919970 Brasilia, DF, Brazil.

F-35042 Rennes, France.

Dept Matemat, BR-13083970 Campinas, SP, Brazil.

Rochester, NY 14627 USA.

Cambridge CB3 9EW, England.

Comment: Regex não será a solução, já que no MySQL ele só serve para "casar" campo com determinado valor, não para extrair esse valor do campo. Se fosse só do Brasil até que era possível, mas com esses dados, não sei não.

Comment: Só preciso do CEP brasileiro sim! 8 dígitos.

Comment: Fazes o select normalmente, e depois e so cortar a string programaticamente.

Comment: Tem que ser feito no workbench, somente usando SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando só os CEPs brasileiros, como você disse nos comentários, você pode usar operações sobre strings para extrair a parte numérica, e `REGEXP` para filtrar os resultados que não contêm CEPs do Brasil:

```
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(endereco, 'BR-', -1), 8) AS CEP
FROM enderecos
WHERE endereco REGEXP 'BR-[0-9]{8}'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e1e3/5

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(endereco, 'BR-', -1)` pega tudo que estiver à direita da primeira ocorrência de "BR-". O `LEFT` isola os primeiros 8 caracteres desse substring.

Comment: Valeu, suspeitava que usando múltiplas funções e expressão regular daria.

Answer (score 0):

Por enquanto MySQL não permite REGEX em REPLACE. Uma forma diferente de se fazer isso é trazer os dados do banco para uma outra linguagem de programação, por exemplo PHP, realizar as operações de extração e devolver ao banco com UPDATE.